# Prioritize traffic going to different interfaces

Tags: linux, traffic, mikrotik, traffic-management

For example, we have regular clients sitting on `wlan1` and Bittorrent client sitting on `eth2`. They access Internet via `eth1`. Bittorrent download traffic should be given lowest priority. So, that Bittorrent download on `eth2` will not hinder regular traffic on `wlan1`. Of course, we cannot prioritize it on `eth1` because it is impossible to prioritize ingress (only shape, but this is absolutely different thing). So, we need to prioritize egress on `wlan1` and `eth2`.

Does queue prioritization work between multiple outgoing interfaces? Otherwise, how this could be possible with Linux traffic control or with Mikrotik?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to be able to create an intermediate queuing device the redirect your traffic through.  The device used to be imq, but now I've seen more documentation about ifb devices.  I've also seen references to using dummy devices as well.  Then you should be able to choose a queuing discipline to attach and either prioritize traffic, or set aside a certain amount of bandwidth for each type.  The links below have a significant amount of information about the idea.  I was going to post more links (including a server fault article), but my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Intermediate Functional Block

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/ifb

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping